# How to delete selected current row in datagrid from SQL (c#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, sql-delete, delete-row

I want to delete selected current row in datagrid from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but it gives syntax error whatever I did. (I will click the row and will delete data in SQL)Here is the codes and errors that I received:

Can you dear friends help me? thanks.

First: ERROR : 'Incorrect syntax near '='.'

```
        private void VeriSİL()
        {
            baglan.Open();

            string bgn = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string m1 = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string m2 = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            string m3 = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            string kturu = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            string m1m = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            string m2m = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            string m3m = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            string urunno = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            string guc = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            string hiz = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            string odk = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
            string gaz = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
            string aci = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
            string noz = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
            string sur = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
            string foto = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[16].Value.ToString();
            string not = cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value.ToString();

            SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("delete from CW where Beğeni = '" + bgn + "' AND [1.Malz] = '" + m1 + "' AND [2.Malz] = '" + m2 + "' AND [3.Malz] = '" + m3 + "' AND Kaynaktürü = '" + kturu + "' AND [1/mm] = '" + m1m + "' AND [2/mm] = '" + m2m + "' AND [3/mm] = '" + m3m + "' AND ÜrünNo = '" + urunno + "'AND Güç = '" + guc + "' AND Hız = '" + hiz + "' AND Gaz = = '" + gaz + "' AND Açı = '" + aci + "' AND Nozzle = '" + noz + "' AND Süre = '" + sur + "' AND Foto= '" + foto + "' AND [Not]= '" + noz + "'", baglan);
            komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
            baglan.Close();
}
   private void silButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VeriSİL();
    }
```

My Second try and the error : 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

```
private void VeriSİL()
         {
                baglan.Open();
                SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Delete CW WHERE Beğeni=@bgn,[1.Malz]=@m1,[2.Malz]=@m2,[3.Malz]=@m3,KaynakTürü=@kturu,[1/mm]=@m1m,[2/mm]=@m2m,[3/mm]=@m3m,Güç=@guc,Hız=@hiz,Odak=@odk,Gaz=@gaz,Açı=@aci,Nozzle=@noz,Süre=@sur,Foto=@foto,[Not]=@not,ÜrünNo=@urunno", baglan);
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bgn", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m1", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m2", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m3", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kturu", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m1m", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m2m", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m3m", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urunno", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guc", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hiz", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odk", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gaz", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aci", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noz", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sur", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foto", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[16].Value.ToString());
                komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@not", cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value.ToString());
                komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Silme İşlemi Başarılı.");
                baglan.Close();
    }
            private void silButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                VeriSİL();
            }
```

My last try and error : 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.'

```
private void VeriSİL()
             {
            baglan.Open();
            SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Delete from CW where Beğeni,[1.Malz],[2.Malz],[3.Malz],KaynakTürü,[1/mm],[2/mm],[3/mm],ÜrünNo,Güç,Hız,Gaz,Odak,Açı,Nozzle,Süre,Foto,[Not] like '" +
                 cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[16].Value.ToString() + "' , '" +
                cwGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value.ToString() + "'", baglan);


            komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Silme İşlemi Başarılı.");
            baglan.Close();
}
                private void silButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    VeriSİL();
                }
```

Comment: You first attempt should be thrown away. It is wide open to sql injection. Your second attempt using parameters is better but your syntax is not valid sql. You probably don't need to look at every single column in your delete, just the primary key.

Comment: First and foremost, learn to use parameters to avoid sql injection and the error you are getting.  Also, if your row has a unique ID field, then you would just delete based on that, and not all of these fields equaling your values, which might still delete more than one record.

Comment: @SeanLange  How can I do that? because I dont use a unique ID.  I have tried "Delete FROM CW Begeni=@bgn..." Delete CW where Begeni=..."
When I researc on internet, I tried most of them (delete from CW, delete CW where..) and all result is same and error. Dou you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Your syntax in the parameter version of your post has all the conditions separated by a comma, which isn't valid syntax.  That probably needs to be an ` AND `.  Put unique IDs in your tables.

Comment: @LarsTech , I tried AND and errors is disappear. When I click delete button, it says delete is succesfully. but nothing changed on sql. 
Also I used ID and tried it, it works. but number of ID is also deleted. when i refresh the table, the ID which I deleted is missing. (ID: 1,3,4,5,6) (I deleted number 2). how can I make auto number after delete?

Comment: You don't worry about the ID number.  It's only used as a row identifier.   It should never be displayed to the user.

Comment: @LarsTech, İ hide that coloumn. thanks for everything.

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)